# adb command not found when trying to use adb to install apk file

Tags: apk, adb

I'm trying to install an apk file in my emulator. I navigated to the directory where the apk file is and typed adb install [name of file].apk

I received this response:

```
-bash: adb: command not found
```

What should I do? Please keep it simple as I don't know much about this.

Answer (score 11):

Type "which adb" in the terminal and see the location of the adb. If no location/ path to adb is displayed, then you should add the location of the platform-tools folder from the android sdk in the system PATH variable.

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/path_to_android_sdk/platform-tools
```

Also, to make the change permanent, you could edit the .bashrc file and add the above line at the end. Save and execute .bashrc.

Comment: This was very helpful for me, thank you! Could You please also include an instruction on how to edit the .bashrc file on Mac (step-by-step for beginners would be great!). Thank you ones again!

Comment: The .bashrc file is located under /Users/your_user folder. You can edit it vith vim or textedit. Just add the line above at the end of the file and save it. I'm sure you can find a step by step tutorial on how to edit the bashrc file. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

your PATH certainly does not include ADB.  it will usually be found inside android sdk paltform-tools (a search for "platform-tools" will usually do the trick).

NOTE: under UBUNUTU 12.04, adt saved android sdk in: /usr/lib/eclipse/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64/sdk/platform-tools